# Hide containing Div when there are no menu items

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hope someone can help,

Im currently working on this website: http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/youth-community/ You can see on this page that the sub menu is showing because there are child pages to show. If you click on 'Contact' the menu doesn't show.

BUT, the blue background div still shows...

Here's my current code:

```
<div class="sub-nav-container-full">
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="sub-page-menu">
      <?php
        $menu = wp_nav_menu(
            array (
              'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
              'sub_menu' => true,
              'echo' => FALSE,
              'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
            )
        );
        if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
        {
        ?>

        <?php
            echo $menu;
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I alter it to say 'if there is no sub menu then hide the containing div;

```
<div class="sub-nav-container-full"></div>
```

To get rid of the blue bar...

Hope someone can help :)

Many thanks,

Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

Option #1, containing div is only created when needed:

```
<?php
  $menu = wp_nav_menu(
      array (
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'sub_menu' => true,
        'echo' => FALSE,
        'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
      )
  );
  if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
  {
    echo '<div class="sub-nav-container-full">
          <div class="container">
          <div class="sub-page-menu">';
    echo $menu;
    echo '</div></div></div>';
  }
?>
```

Option #2: Containing div always exists, but hidden if empty. Add a `else` block like that:

```
  // same as before
  if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
  {
    // same as before
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<div class="sub-nav-container-full" style="display: none;">
          <div class="container">
          <div class="sub-page-menu">';
    echo '</div></div></div>';
  }
```

*Consider using `visibility: hidden`, instead of `display: none`. Element won't show, but it still takes up space in the layout.*

*Option #2 can be easily optimized reducing repeated lines.*

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div class="sub-nav-container-full">
  <div class="container"> 
      <?php
        $menu = wp_nav_menu(
            array (
              'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
              'sub_menu' => true,
              'echo' => FALSE,
              'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
            )
        );
        if ( ! empty ( $menu ) )
        {
            echo '<div class="sub-page-menu">'.$menu.'</div>';
        }
      ?>
  </div>
</div>
```